# Не могу создать триггер

Tags: mysql, триггер

Добрый день.
Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE buffer (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ad_type varchar(20),
    price varchar(20),
    description varchar(1000),
    params varchar(500),
    image varchar(300),
    ins_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

А также таблица источник tbl_temp с полями type, price, comments, house, level, photo.
Пытаюсь сделать триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'update_tbl' AFTER INSERT ON 'tbl_temp'
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO buffer SET ad_type = NEW.type, price = REPLACE(NEW.price, 'руб.',''), description = NEW.comments, ad_params = CONCAT(NEW.house, ' ', level), image = NEW.photo
END;
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''update_tbl' AFTER INSERT ON 'tbl_temp'
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT IN' at line 1
```

Я понял, что ошибка в INSERT, но вот где именно так и не разобрался. Не могли бы вы помочь?
Спасибо!

Comment: У вас после оператора insert нет точки с запятой.

Comment: Аналогичная ошибка:
INSERT INTO buffer (ad_type, price, description, ad_params, image) VALUES (NEW.type, REPLACE(NEW.price, 'руб.',''), NEW.comments,  CONCAT(NEW.house, ' ', NEW.level), NEW.photo); С точкой запятой тоже самое.

Comment: @Mike Специально для вас залез в справочник. SET используется в INSERT. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: @balamutik Да, насчет SET я погорячился, mysql видимо единственный такую форму insert имеет ... А в вашем триггере ошибка возможно в том, что имя триггера и таблицы заключено в одинарные прямые кавычки. Имена таблиц и полей в MySQL пишутся в обратных апострофах (обычно слева от 1 на клавиатуре), либо без них.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема была в BEGIN и END. Убрал их и триггер создался